# Eclipse ARM development

Tags: eclipse, arm

I am failing the very [fist step](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/arm/install/) in getting Eclipse (which is completely new to me) ready for ARM development.

I installed Eclipse in windows 10. I think I am supposed to install xpm, but I have no idea where to type in this command:

xpm install --global @gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc

Or is this for linux users only?

PS: I installed the cpp edition of Eclipse, that's all I have at the moment.

Comment: Note that IDEs are not required for software development on most targets (the exceptions are ones where there are no standalone tools).  ARM has standalone tools that the IDEs call and you can simply call them directly.  There are also countless text editors out there.  I would separate development and installation of a tool from each other.  you can start arm development now and figure out the tool later or try several tools and pick one you like either from its features, ease of use or ease of installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference (maybe only for myself :))

UPDATE:
After reading a lot about ARM development I finally came on the path of STM32. There is a great book available via leanpub: Mastering STM32. 
The free available sample describes in great detail how to setup the tool chain for ARM development in Eclipse. I managed to get it working that way, so probably everybody can :).

The link to the book:
https://www.carminenoviello.com/mastering-stm32/
Chapter 2.

---

UPDATE:

https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/org.eclipse.epp.packages/releases/

---

Install node.js, which can be downloaded here:
https://nodejs.org/en/

After install nodejs, install xpm as follows:

```
npm install --global xpm
```

Then, install the toolchain for Eclipse:

```
xpm install --global @gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

Install the build-tools (windows only):

```
xpm install --global @gnu-mcu-eclipse/windows-build-tools
```

Install CDT

- Start Eclipse
- Help
- Install new software
- Work with type 'Neon' (autocompletes in 'GNU MCU...')
- Expand 'Programming language'
- Install 'C/C++ Development Tools' and next next finish, restart Eclipse

Install CMSIS

- Start Eclipse
- Help
- Install new software
- Work with 'All available sites'
- Search for 'CMSIS'
- Check 'GNU/ARM C/C++ Packs (experimental)
- Next, next, finish

Install GNU MCU Eclipse via marketplace

- Start Eclipse
- Help
- Marketplace
- Search for 'GNU MCU Eclipse'
- Install
- Restart Eclipse

First test project

- Start Eclipse
- File
- New C++ project
- A managed build (CDT)
- Project name 'test'
- Executable 'STM32F7xx C/C++ Project'
- Next
- Use system calls 'Semihosting (POSIX system calls via host)'
- Next, Next, Next, Finish

Assign board

- Right click Test project
- Properties
- C/C++ build
- Settings

  ### - Devices

Follow the remaining steps described [here](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/tutorials/blinky-arm/)

Answer (score 3):

You should install DS-5 instead.

DS-5 is an IDE for ARM systems published by none other than ARM itself, based on Eclipse.

The community edition is free of charge.

https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/editions/community-edition

All you have to do is to install DS-5 community edition plus the right toolchains for your target, released by Linaro.

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/

Below is how to add the toolchains to the environment:

https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/adding-new-compiler-toolchains-to-ds-5

Comment: Ah thanks a million! Will try this ASAP! The eclipse approach is really up hill.... Still haven't got everything in place...!

Comment: Bleh, followed the steps, installed the toolchain, followed the tutorial and get all kind of compiler errors on the hello world example... Djeeze, getting started in ARM microcontroller development isn't if you can't spend money :). I'll give the eclipse MCU another go, at least there I had something that compiled..

Comment: @bas What's the final verdict regarding the Arm dev tools, which way to go?

Comment: Hey, I went for eclipse in the end with stm32 chips :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that with [Eclipse 4.17 (2020_09 release)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#arm64) you now have

> ### Builds for Linux AArch64 (aka Arm64) added
>
> Binaries for Linux AArch64 (Arm64) are available for testing.
> With the raising popularity of this architecture people can continue using the Eclipse IDE even when changing their machine.

See [bug 565836](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565836), [CL 167308](https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt/+/167308) and [commit 149ccaf](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=149ccaffccafbccc8d5f35cfe9ea52ca41a5e22c).